# Mqtt con React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mqtt

Tengo la pagina web en React y necesito conectarla a MQTT para pasar datos de los sensores.

He creado el archivo mqtt.js dentro de los src

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt/dist/mqtt')
const client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://broker.hivemq.com:1883')

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('presence', function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt')
    }
  })
})

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer
  console.log(message.toString())
  client.end()
})
```

Pero a mi me sigue saliendo el error que no se puede conectarse [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy nueva en React y he visto muchos videos ya y no entiendo por que no se conecta.

Answer (score 1):

En React la Librería MQTT.js solo funciona con websockets, intenta cambiar numero de puerto del broker a uno que soporte MQTT sobre websockets.

Por ejemplo el broker online de Mosquitto usa los siguientes puertos:

- 8080 : MQTT over WebSockets, unencrypted, unauthenticated
- 8081 : MQTT over WebSockets, encrypted, unauthenticated
- 8090 : MQTT over WebSockets, unencrypted, authenticated

Adicionalmente puedes ver este ejemplo que funciona a la perfección con React y la Librería MQTT.js [Taste MQTT react](https://www.preciouschicken.com/blog/posts/a-taste-of-mqtt-in-react/)

Answer (score 0):

Dejo por si a alguien le sirve. Para que funcione en lugar de poner mqtt hay que poner ws(WebSocket), ejemplo: ws://broker.hivemq.com:1883

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt/dist/mqtt')
const client  = mqtt.connect('ws://broker.hivemq.com:1883')
```